# How to limit web site access to USA or North America only

Tags: asp.net, security

This is a corporate site so Private. We want to limit access by IP address to USA/Canada or North America. Based on IP range, would allow user/pwd to get in otherwise -'no access'. Just trying to limit hack exposure from anything overseas.

Comment: Yeah, I would do the same if I lived on your continent. Everyone over here (Europe) are just lame script kiddies. What's the address of that website, btw? :p

Comment: Blocking other countries' IP addresses to prevent hacking attacks from abroad sounds like a stupid idea. First, you will block a lot of legitimate traffic, too: Armed forces overseas, other americans abroad, american IPs with false positives, and so on. Second, IPs can be spoofed, or working IPs acquired by any serious hacker.

Comment: This is not something you want to use "code" to solve. This is a network issue. If you want to limit traffic, it should be done at the network routers with appropriate firewalls and IPSEC.

Comment: I mean no disrespect to other countries, our applicable financial Law is only enforceable in USA, so wanted to limit non-applicable areas, and potential bots. I'm learning - all comments valid - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your main aim is to prevent unauthorized access to your website by IP... that will never ever work. Its so easy to bypass that. a user/pwd would be a more secure option.

To answer your question, if you have certain features or a complete website block that you want to do, this is a tutorial:

http://blog.newagesolution.net/2008/11/how-to-block-country-and-ip-addresses.html

Comment: Although it's not in the question, it's tagged `asp.net`

Comment: this requires IIS and ASP so it does not work with Apache and/or php.

Answer (score 3):

Anybody who could get past your password security could easily get past any IP filtering security (and it may even be seen as a challenge, thus increasing the risk of overseas hacking). I think the premise of your question is flawed.

Comment: Agree 100%, but this kind of thing tends to come down from highly-placed executives who assume it's possible because "all the big companies have this information" and won't hear anything else, even the truth that it's only an easily-circumvented approximation.

Comment: there are many many script kiddies who cannot bypass password security but can exploit wordpress and other cms's holes with simple scripts ... this solution would cut down on that- and leave the ones who DO this sort of thing liable since they are in the same country.

Answer (score 2):

There are various libraries that will do geocoding of IP address.  The one I've used is [GeoIP](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/geoip-targetting#), which has a free version.

Note that IP addresses can be spoofable, so anyone wanting to get around your check will be able to.  Any serious hackers won't be very deterred.