# How to limit web site access to USA only

Tags: iis, asp-classic

how do I limit my website access to USA only, using ASP Classic (windows server). I read about htaccess, but not sure how to implement that to ASP classic programming language.

Comment: The .htaccess file is specific to Apache servers and Classic ASP runs on IIS only.  Anyway, you would need to block IP ranges, and that's something which you would need to do with your server firewall settings rather than through Classic ASP.  This question is worth a read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111246/how-to-limit-web-site-access-to-usa-or-north-america-only

Comment: Also @John blacklisting IPs is a poor implementation as they are easily spoofed.

Comment: You will have all the success that Netflix had: i.e. none

Answer (score 1):

You can add htaccess-functionality by implementing an IIS-Module (i.e. [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/)) which allows you to set IP-Ranges. Such a module has to be installed on your Windows Webserver (Server 2008 and above) and will be configured in your IIS-Manager. Once this is done you are able to use htaccess in nearly the same way as on an Apache Server.

Another (theoratical) way is to do a server-side check on the remote IP-address.

First you need to retrieve the remote IP-address

```
remote_addr = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR");
```

Then you can compare against given ranges

```
function compareIps(ip, lowrange, highrange)
   dim octetIPArray(4) as integer, octetIPLowArray(4) as integer, octetIPHighArray(4) as integer
   compareIps = False
   octetArray = split(ip, '.', -1, vbtextcompare)
   octetIPLowArray = split(lowrange, '.', -1, vbtextcompare)
   octetIPHighArray = split(highrange, '.', -1, vbtextcompare)

   for i = 0 to 3
      if octetArray(i) >= octetIPLowArray(i) and octetArray(i) <= octetIPHighArray(i) then
         compareIps = True
         exit function
      end if
   next
    end function

if compareIps(remote_addr, "3.0.0.0","3.255.255.255")=True then
   response.end
end if
```

Please note that in case of US IP-traffic there are [quite a few ranges](http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/us.html) to block (nearly 7.000).

As already commented, IPs can be spoofed so it's not a 100% safe method at all.